# server.transfer in another web page

Tags: asp.net

What will happen when we are using Server.Transfer and want to do some task on another page but by some reasons task get failed like userid has been blocked in this situation what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always advisable to use the Server.Transfer when moving from one page to another in asp.net. If you use the Transfer method which make sure that all the object stored in the session and application scope are remain unchanged.

But if you are using asp.net ajax enabled page then Server.Transfer doesn't serve it purpose. You need to use the Response.Redirect instead of Server.Transfer in the asp.net ajax enabled pages.